# Doctrine custom data type

Tags: mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine, dbal

I'm developing application with Symfony2. Symfony2 is using Doctrine 2 for DBAL and ORM. As far as I know Doctrine2 doesn't have suport for BLOB data type. However I want to implement BLOB support through the custom data type mapping:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/types.html

However I'm struggling to understand where should this part go.

```
<?php
Type::addType('money', 'My\Project\Types\MoneyType');
$conn->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('MyMoney', 'money');
```

Is anybody was going through it?

The reason I need a BLOB type is that I want to import mapping from existing MySQL database.

Comment: just answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9133207/433927

Answer (score 9):

Another solution would be to register your Custom Type in the config file

You just need to add that in your config file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            money:  My\Project\Types\MoneyType
```

You can find more info on how to register a custom mapping type in this [Symfony Cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html)

Answer (score 4):

According to the link in previous answer you can just add it to `src/My/Project/MyProjectBundle.php`

```
use My\Project\Types\MoneyType;

class MyProject extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        Type::addType('money', MoneyType::class);
        $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('MyMoney','money');
    }
}
```